# Android: Play a new game in the app rather than downloading it from play store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am new to android development and i have a question that i am not able to find on the internet.

CASE:
An app XYZ, is on play store.
Once you download, install and open it, it shows a list of games available in the app itself, like 1) Hangman 2) Tic Tac Toe 3) Chess etc etc.
These games are not yet available for playing; its only a list of games available in XYZ.
Once the user clicks on a game he wants to play, like Hangman, gets downloaded and can be played from the app itself [unlike play store's open app].
If the user wishes to download another game, he can do so.

My Questions: Is it even possible?
If yes, then where do i find resources on doing this?
How do i structure my app so that it enables such a feature.

I want to do this so that the app size is small and games that user likes can be downloaded and played from app itself.

Answer (score 0):

to get list of installed apps.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

to get the app tittles

```
           for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : packages) {
                String title = (String)((appInfo != null) ? pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo) : "unknown");
            }
```

you can match the tittle with your list. If it is there you can start the app by

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appInfo.packageName);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

if the app is not installed then redirect to the  corresponding app store page

Comment: Can it be possible to make the games part of the app and not a different game itself?